# Unexplainable error message with a plot using tikz and pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

I am having a problem with a plot which I am unable to explain, let alone fix.

A simple example is this (there is also a curve plotted from data, but I skipped it as it doesn't affect the outcome):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.7]
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=0,
        xmax=0.08,
        ymin=0.04,
        ymax=0.12,
        xtick=\empty,
        ytick=\empty,
        xlabel={$\scriptscriptstyle \sigma$},
        ylabel={$\scriptscriptstyle \mu$},
        ytick={0.05,0.088,0.0947,0.1},
        yticklabels={\color{teal} $\scriptscriptstyle 5\%$,\color{blue} $\scriptscriptstyle 8.8\%$,\color{blue} $\scriptscriptstyle 9.47\%$,\color{blue} $\scriptscriptstyle 10\%$},
        xtick={0.0447,0.0485,0.0542},
        xticklabels={\color{blue} $\scriptscriptstyle 4.47\%$,\color{blue} $\scriptscriptstyle 4.85\%$,\color{blue} $\scriptscriptstyle 5.42\%$},
        every axis y label/.style={
            at={(ticklabel* cs:1.01)},
            anchor=south,
        },
        x label style={at={(axis description cs:1,-0.01)},anchor=south},
        x tick label style={yshift={-mod(\ticknum,2)*1em}},
        title={\footnotesize Efficient frontier}
        ]
        
        \draw [dashed, color=blue] (axis cs:0,0.088) --  (axis cs:0.0447,0.088);
        \draw [dashed, color=blue] (axis cs:0,0.0947) --  (axis cs:0.0485,0.0947);
        \draw [dashed, color=blue] (axis cs:0,0.1) --  (axis cs:0.0542,0.1);
        \draw [dashed, color=blue] (axis cs:0.0447,0) --  (axis cs:0.0447,0.088);
        \draw [dashed, color=blue] (axis cs:0.0485,0) --  (axis cs:0.0485,0.0947);
        \draw [dashed, color=blue] (axis cs:0.0542,0) --  (axis cs:0.0542,0.1);
            
        \draw[blue,fill=blue] (axis cs:0.0447,0.088) circle[radius=1] node[below left,blue]{$\scriptscriptstyle mvp$};
        \draw[blue,fill=blue] (axis cs:0.0485,0.0947) circle[radius=1] node[right,blue]{$\scriptscriptstyle T$};
        \draw[blue,fill=blue] (axis cs:0.0542,0.1) circle[radius=1] node[above,blue]{$\scriptscriptstyle p$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This code provides the following plot:

[image]

In addition, I get the following error messages:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> -mod(\ticknum 
                         ,2)*1em
l.50        \end{axis}
                 
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.50        \end{axis}
                 
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

However, if I run the following code (again without data), everything is nice and there is no error message:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.7]
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=0.04,
        xmax=0.22,
        ymin=0.05,
        ymax=0.22,
        xtick=\empty,
        ytick=\empty,
        xlabel={$\scriptscriptstyle \sigma$},
        ylabel={$\scriptscriptstyle \mu$},
        ytick={0.1,0.1082,0.1401,0.2},
        yticklabels={\color{red} $\scriptscriptstyle 10\%$,\color{blue} $\scriptscriptstyle 10.82\%$,\color{blue} $\scriptscriptstyle 14.01\%$,\color{red} $\scriptscriptstyle 20\%$},
        xtick={0.09,0.1,0.2},
        xticklabels={\color{blue} $\scriptscriptstyle 9\%$,\color{red} $\scriptscriptstyle 10\%$,\color{red} $\scriptscriptstyle 20\%$},
        every axis y label/.style={
            at={(ticklabel* cs:1.01)},
            anchor=south,
        },
        x label style={at={(axis description cs:1,-0.01)},anchor=south},
        x tick label style={yshift={-mod(\ticknum,2)*1em}},
        title={\footnotesize Minimum-variance frontier}
        ]
        
        \draw [dashed, color=red] (axis cs:0,0.1) --  (axis cs:0.1,0.1);
        \draw [dashed, color=blue] (axis cs:0,0.1082) --  (axis cs:0.09,0.1082);
        \draw [dashed, color=blue] (axis cs:0,0.1401) --  (axis cs:0.09,0.1401);
        \draw [dashed, color=red] (axis cs:0,0.2) --  (axis cs:0.2,0.2);
        \draw [dashed, color=blue] (axis cs:0.09,0) --  (axis cs:0.09,0.1401);
        \draw [dashed, color=red] (axis cs:0.1,0) --  (axis cs:0.1,0.1);
        \draw [dashed, color=red] (axis cs:0.2,0) --  (axis cs:0.2,0.2);
                
        \draw[blue,fill=blue] (axis cs:0.09,0.1082) circle[radius=1] node[right,blue]{$\scriptscriptstyle I$};
        \draw[blue,fill=blue] (axis cs:0.09,0.1401) circle[radius=1] node[right,blue]{$\scriptscriptstyle E$};
        \draw[red,fill=red] (axis cs:0.1,0.1) circle[radius=1] node[below right,red]{{\tiny Stock 1}};
        \draw[red,fill=red] (axis cs:0.2,0.2) circle[radius=1] node[above,red]{{\tiny Stock 2}};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I know that the error is in this part:

```
x label style={at={(axis description cs:1,-0.01)},anchor=south},
x tick label style={yshift={-mod(\ticknum,2)*1em}},
```

but I'm just unable to find out what's going on. The two codes are almost identical, essentially only the numbers differ, but somehow the first doesn't work and that strange `$\dot 10^{-2}$` appears in the down-right corner.

I am grateful for any help.

Comment: Have you already tried reading the error message?  It says that `\ticknum` is undefined in this context.

Comment: Additionally please change these into compilable examples, you could use the `standalone` class plus the needed preamble for these examples. Then it is easy to copy and test your code.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The error really seems to arise because of the scaled x axis (altough I don't have a clue why). Adding `scaled x ticks=false` to the `axis` options doesn't raise the error, but please check, if the output numbers are right/as expected.

Comment: I read the error message indeed, but I don't really understand it. The code works perfectly in one case and gives an error in another.

Comment: I am sorry, I am new here and I just pasted the tikzpicture part of the code and not the whole one. When I copied the full code, part of it didn't appear as a code. I still need to learn how to use this...

Comment: Stefan Pinnow, now it works perfectly, thank you! I still have no idea why it is needed in the first code and not in the second, but at least I have a working solution. Highly appreciated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments.